# USB headset not working properly

Tags: linux-mint, usb, audio

I have a Corsair Vengeance 1500 USB Headset and I'm using linux Mint.

My headset doesn't always immediately work when connecting it to my pc, but most of the time the headset works. Sometimes the driver (I suspect) suddenly shuts down for a couple minutes. Sometimes I can get it back by reloading the alsa modules (`alsa force-reload`) but not always.

Also, sometimes during boot (after logging in, before I see my desktop) it hangs for a minute, showing me only a black screen with my cursor, and when it finally continues my desktop isn't loaded properly (no wallpaper and wrong themes). When I disconnect my headset before booting this never happens.

Anyway, lots of weird issues and my linux-foo isn't good enough to track these down. I can provide log files if you need them, but I have no clue what you might need so just ask.

Log when it disconnects and reloading alsa afterwards:

```
Sep  2 09:27:05 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1302.981901] hub 3-0:1.0: port 6 disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
Sep  2 09:27:05 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1302.981912] usb 3-6: USB disconnect, device number 7
Sep  2 09:27:10 shrine2gaben pulseaudio[2207]: [alsa-sink-USB Audio] alsa-mixer.c: Error handling mixer event: No such device
Sep  2 09:27:10 shrine2gaben pulseaudio[2207]: [alsa-source-USB Audio] alsa-source.c: snd_pcm_avail: No such device
Sep  2 09:27:10 shrine2gaben pulseaudio[2207]: [alsa-source-USB Audio] alsa-mixer.c: Failed to set switch of Line: No such device
Sep  2 09:27:11 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1308.277560] usb 3-6: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Sep  2 09:27:11 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1308.294895] usb 3-6: New USB device found, idVendor=1b1c, idProduct=0a03
Sep  2 09:27:11 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1308.294904] usb 3-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Sep  2 09:27:11 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1308.294908] usb 3-6: Product: Corsair Vengeance 1500
Sep  2 09:27:11 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1308.294912] usb 3-6: Manufacturer: Corsair Components, Inc.
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1408.358809] usb_audio: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=640), cval->res is probably wrong.
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.37 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.37 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.37 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.37 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: hci0: Remove UUID (0x0011) failed: Busy (0x0a)
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 4787 of process 4787 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 4866 of process 4787 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 4927 of process 4787 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 4931 of process 4787 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.66 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.66 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.66 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  2 09:28:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.66 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  2 09:28:56 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1408.358819] usb_audio: [13] FU [Mic Playback Volume] ch = 2, val = -7424/2816/16<6>[ 1413.363915] usbcore: deregistering interface driver snd-usb-audio
Sep  2 09:29:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1441.515193] INFO: task systemd-udevd:4714 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Sep  2 09:29:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1441.515208]       Tainted: G           OX 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu
Sep  2 09:29:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1441.515213] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Sep  2 09:29:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1441.515219] systemd-udevd   D ffff88042fa94480     0  4714    399 0x00000004
Sep  2 09:29:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1441.515233]  ffff88030918fdd0 0000000000000082 ffff880322004800 ffff88030918ffd8
Sep  2 09:29:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1441.515246]  0000000000014480 0000000000014480 ffff880322004800 ffff88038e3730e8
Sep  2 09:29:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1441.515259]  ffff88038e3730ec ffff880322004800 00000000ffffffff ffff88038e3730f0
Sep  2 09:29:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1441.515275] Call Trace:
Sep  2 09:29:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1441.515301]  [<ffffffff81723649>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0x29/0x70
Sep  2 09:29:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1441.515317]  [<ffffffff817254b5>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x135/0x1b0
Sep  2 09:29:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1441.515331]  [<ffffffff8172554f>] mutex_lock+0x1f/0x2f
Sep  2 09:29:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1441.515349]  [<ffffffff8154d1c9>] read_descriptors+0x39/0x110
Sep  2 09:29:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1441.515361]  [<ffffffff8123319b>] ? sysfs_bin_read+0x8b/0x1d0
Sep  2 09:29:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1441.515369]  [<ffffffff812331ee>] sysfs_bin_read+0xde/0x1d0
Sep  2 09:29:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1441.515382]  [<ffffffff811bd075>] vfs_read+0x95/0x160
Sep  2 09:29:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1441.515393]  [<ffffffff811bdb89>] SyS_read+0x49/0xa0
Sep  2 09:29:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1441.515405]  [<ffffffff8172f82d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
Sep  2 09:29:32 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.66 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  2 09:29:32 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.66 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  2 09:29:32 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.66 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  2 09:29:32 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.66 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  2 09:29:32 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: hci0: Remove UUID (0x0011) failed: Busy (0x0a)
Sep  2 09:29:32 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10211 of process 10211 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Sep  2 09:29:32 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:32 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10212 of process 10211 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:32 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:32 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10213 of process 10211 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:32 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:32 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10214 of process 10211 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:32 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:32 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  2 09:29:32 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  2 09:29:32 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  2 09:29:32 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  2 09:29:34 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  2 09:29:34 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  2 09:29:34 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  2 09:29:34 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.71 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  2 09:29:34 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: hci0: Remove UUID (0x0011) failed: Busy (0x0a)
Sep  2 09:29:34 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10310 of process 10310 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Sep  2 09:29:34 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:34 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10311 of process 10310 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:34 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:34 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10312 of process 10310 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:34 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:34 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10313 of process 10310 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:34 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:34 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  2 09:29:34 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  2 09:29:34 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  2 09:29:34 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  2 09:29:35 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  2 09:29:35 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  2 09:29:35 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  2 09:29:35 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  2 09:29:35 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: hci0: Remove UUID (0x0011) failed: Busy (0x0a)
Sep  2 09:29:35 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10408 of process 10408 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Sep  2 09:29:35 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:35 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10409 of process 10408 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:35 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:35 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10410 of process 10408 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:35 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:35 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10411 of process 10408 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:35 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:35 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.81 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  2 09:29:35 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.81 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  2 09:29:35 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.81 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  2 09:29:35 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.81 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  2 09:29:36 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.81 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  2 09:29:36 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.81 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  2 09:29:36 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.81 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  2 09:29:36 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.81 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  2 09:29:36 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: hci0: Remove UUID (0x0011) failed: Busy (0x0a)
Sep  2 09:29:36 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10506 of process 10506 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Sep  2 09:29:36 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:36 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10507 of process 10506 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:36 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:36 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10508 of process 10506 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:36 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:36 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10509 of process 10506 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:36 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:37 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  2 09:29:37 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  2 09:29:37 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  2 09:29:37 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  2 09:29:37 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  2 09:29:37 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  2 09:29:37 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  2 09:29:37 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.86 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  2 09:29:37 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: hci0: Remove UUID (0x0011) failed: Busy (0x0a)
Sep  2 09:29:37 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10607 of process 10607 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Sep  2 09:29:37 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:39 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10699 of process 10607 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:39 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:39 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10749 of process 10607 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:39 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:39 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10757 of process 10607 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:39 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:39 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.91 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  2 09:29:39 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.91 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  2 09:29:39 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.91 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  2 09:29:39 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.91 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  2 09:29:41 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1458.389479] 14:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 14)
Sep  2 09:29:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.91 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  2 09:29:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.91 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  2 09:29:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.91 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  2 09:29:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.91 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  2 09:29:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: hci0: Remove UUID (0x0011) failed: Busy (0x0a)
Sep  2 09:29:51 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10871 of process 10871 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Sep  2 09:29:51 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:51 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10934 of process 10871 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:51 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:51 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10971 of process 10871 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:51 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:51 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Successfully made thread 10975 of process 10871 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep  2 09:29:51 shrine2gaben rtkit-daemon[2210]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Sep  2 09:29:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.96 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Sep  2 09:29:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.96 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Sep  2 09:29:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.96 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Sep  2 09:29:51 shrine2gaben bluetoothd[580]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.96 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Sep  2 09:30:31 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1508.420067] 9:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 9)
Sep  2 09:31:21 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1558.450697] 10:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 10)
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588576] INFO: task upowerd:2218 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588582]       Tainted: G           OX 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588583] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588585] upowerd         D ffff88042fa94480     0  2218      1 0x00000000
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588590]  ffff8804152c5dd0 0000000000000082 ffff8800baf0b000 ffff8804152c5fd8
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588594]  0000000000014480 0000000000014480 ffff8800baf0b000 ffff8804190660e8
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588597]  ffff8804190660ec ffff8800baf0b000 00000000ffffffff ffff8804190660f0
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588600] Call Trace:
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588609]  [<ffffffff81723649>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0x29/0x70
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588614]  [<ffffffff817254b5>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x135/0x1b0
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588618]  [<ffffffff8172554f>] mutex_lock+0x1f/0x2f
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588623]  [<ffffffff8154d1c9>] read_descriptors+0x39/0x110
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588627]  [<ffffffff8123319b>] ? sysfs_bin_read+0x8b/0x1d0
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588629]  [<ffffffff812331ee>] sysfs_bin_read+0xde/0x1d0
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588634]  [<ffffffff811bd075>] vfs_read+0x95/0x160
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588637]  [<ffffffff811bdb89>] SyS_read+0x49/0xa0
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588640]  [<ffffffff8172f82d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588680] INFO: task systemd-udevd:4714 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588682]       Tainted: G           OX 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588683] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588685] systemd-udevd   D ffff88042fa94480     0  4714    399 0x00000004
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588688]  ffff88030918fdd0 0000000000000082 ffff880322004800 ffff88030918ffd8
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588691]  0000000000014480 0000000000014480 ffff880322004800 ffff88038e3730e8
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588694]  ffff88038e3730ec ffff880322004800 00000000ffffffff ffff88038e3730f0
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588697] Call Trace:
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588701]  [<ffffffff81723649>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0x29/0x70
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588704]  [<ffffffff817254b5>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x135/0x1b0
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588708]  [<ffffffff8172554f>] mutex_lock+0x1f/0x2f
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588711]  [<ffffffff8154d1c9>] read_descriptors+0x39/0x110
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588714]  [<ffffffff8123319b>] ? sysfs_bin_read+0x8b/0x1d0
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588716]  [<ffffffff812331ee>] sysfs_bin_read+0xde/0x1d0
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588720]  [<ffffffff811bd075>] vfs_read+0x95/0x160
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588723]  [<ffffffff811bdb89>] SyS_read+0x49/0xa0
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588725]  [<ffffffff8172f82d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588728] INFO: task modprobe:10185 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588730]       Tainted: G           OX 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588731] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588732] modprobe        D ffff88042fb14480     0 10185      1 0x00000004
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588735]  ffff88033f977e18 0000000000000082 ffff8804134d3000 ffff88033f977fd8
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588738]  0000000000014480 0000000000014480 ffff8804134d3000 ffff8804134d3000
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588741]  ffff8803b16e41e8 ffffffffa0729f90 00007f4c7940f340 00007fffff110958
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588744] Call Trace:
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588748]  [<ffffffff81723129>] schedule+0x29/0x70
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588752]  [<ffffffff8170cd85>] klist_remove+0xa5/0xe0
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588757]  [<ffffffff81232b05>] ? sysfs_remove_file_ns+0x15/0x20
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588761]  [<ffffffff81495504>] bus_remove_driver+0x44/0xd0
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588764]  [<ffffffff8149691c>] driver_unregister+0x2c/0x50
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588767]  [<ffffffff81548740>] usb_deregister+0x70/0xe0
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588775]  [<ffffffffa071e1e9>] usb_audio_driver_exit+0x10/0xe27 [snd_usb_audio]
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588778]  [<ffffffff810e00f2>] SyS_delete_module+0x162/0x200
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588783]  [<ffffffff81013df7>] ? do_notify_resume+0x97/0xb0
Sep  2 09:31:24 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1561.588786]  [<ffffffff8172f82d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
Sep  2 09:32:11 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1608.489313] 11:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 11)
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1633.504604] usbhid 3-6:1.3: can't add hid device: -110
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1633.504625] usbhid: probe of 3-6:1.3 failed with error -110
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1633.504726] hub 3-0:1.0: port 6 disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1633.504732] usb 3-6: USB disconnect, device number 8
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1633.508868] systemd-udevd[11058]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/snd/pcmC2D0c: No such file or directory
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1633.508877] systemd-udevd[11058]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/snd/pcmC2D0c: No such file or directory
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1633.508985] systemd-udevd[11057]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/snd/pcmC2D0p: No such file or directory
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1633.509000] systemd-udevd[11057]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/snd/pcmC2D0p: No such file or directory
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1633.509680] systemd-udevd[11059]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/snd/controlC2: No such file or directory
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1633.509698] systemd-udevd[11059]: Failed to apply ACL on /dev/snd/controlC2: No such file or directory
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1633.744825] usb 3-6: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1633.762414] usb 3-6: New USB device found, idVendor=1b1c, idProduct=0a03
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1633.762426] usb 3-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1633.762433] usb 3-6: Product: Corsair Vengeance 1500
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1633.762439] usb 3-6: Manufacturer: Corsair Components, Inc.
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1633.764527] input: Corsair Components, Inc. Corsair Vengeance 1500 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.3/input/input25
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben kernel: [ 1633.764928] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:0A03.0005: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.00 Device [Corsair Components, Inc. Corsair Vengeance 1500] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input3
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6"
Sep  2 09:32:36 shrine2gaben mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 9 was not an MTP device
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Mint are you running? 17.2? Cinnamon or MATE desktop?

> I have a Corsair Vengeance 1500 USB Headset and I'm using linux Mint.
>
> My headset doesn't always immediately work when connecting it to my
>   pc, but most of the time the headset works. Sometimes the driver (I
>   suspect) suddenly shuts down for a couple minutes. Sometimes I can get
>   it back by reloading the alsa modules (alsa force-reload) but not
>   always.

Are you selecting the correct audio output? I have a USB headset on LM 17.2 Cinnamon, and when I plug it in I often have to manually set the audio output to the headset (vs. the speakers). To do this, you click on the speaker icon in the taskbar, then click "Output device..." and then choose your headset.

I suspect that when you do `alsa force-reload` it may force Mint to choose the right output.

I can't speak to the booting issue but that doesn't sound like an audio problem to me. Are you sure that plugging in your headset before boot is the ONLY thing that causes the login problem?

Comment: I'm using 17.1 (Cinnamon).

Keep in mind most of the time everything works fine, proper output selected and everyone's happy. But then it randomly breaks and the output disappears from the list. Sometimes reloading alsa works, but I think it's just breaks for 1-2 minutes, then it usually gets back up automatically. And yes, so far the boot issue seems to correlate perfectly with (un)plugging my headset

Comment: OK, my next suggestion would be to take a look at your log files. Fire up the Log File Viewer, look at the dmesg output and search for 'usb' , 'alsa', etc. and see whether you see any errors or warnings.

Comment: Beyond that, have you tried plugging your headset into different ports? I had one mobo with an integrated usb 2.0 controller and a third-party usb 3.0 controller, and several peripherals wouldn't play nicely with the third-party controller.

Comment: I've added a syslog to my main post. Will try another usb port when I have some more time.

Comment: Well, as you figured out, the problem seems to start when the USB port you're plugged in to gets disabled:

```
 hub 3-0:1.0: port 6 disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
```

That sounds like a hardware or interference issue. See http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/usb-port-nn-disabled-by-hub-emi-re-enabling-841593/.

Comment: Indeed, but on my windows installation I never have any troubles and the hardware is exactly the same...

Comment: Unfortunately it's a fact of life with Linux that sometimes the developers of Windows drivers can get information from the device manufacturer about hardware bugs and required workarounds, while the same information is not necessarily available for Linux driver developers.